Solving a PDE using Nehari manifold and Ekeland variational principle
Consider $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^N$ be a bounded domain, $2 < p < 2^\ast$ and $\|\cdot\|$ the usual norm of $H^1_{0}(\Omega)$. I want to find a non trivial weak solution of
$$
\begin{cases}
-\Delta u = |u|^{p-2}u, \Omega \\
u = 0, \partial \Omega
\end{cases},
$$
which is a critical point of the functinal $\Phi : H^1_{0}(\Omega) \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by
$$\Phi(u) = \frac{1}{2}\|u\|^2 - \frac{1}{p}\int_{\Omega} |u|^p.$$
I want such a solution to be in the Nehari Manifold
$$
\mathcal{N} := \{u \in H^1_{0}(\Omega)\backslash\{0\} : \Psi(u) = 0\},
$$
where
$$
\Psi(u) : = \Phi'(u) u = \|u\|^2 - \int_B |u|^p.
$$
I have already proved the results:


For each $u \in H^{1}_{0}(\Omega)$ with $u\neq 0$ there exists a unique $t_u>0$ such that $t_u u \in \mathcal{N}$ and
$$
  \Phi(t_u u) = \max \{\Phi(t u) : t > 0\}.
  $$
$\Phi(u)> 0$ for every $u \in \mathcal{N}$.
Every minimizing sequence of $c = \inf_{u \in \mathcal{N}}\{\Phi(u)\}$ is bounded in $H^{1}_{0}(\Omega)$.
There exists a constant $C$ such that $0 < C \leq \|u\|$ for all $u \in \mathcal{N}$.
For any $w \in \mathcal{N}$, $\Psi'(w)w < -(p-2)\|w\|$.
By 4) and 5),  $\Psi'(w)w < -(p-2)C$, for any $w \in \mathcal{N}$. In particular, $-1/[(p-2)C] < 1/[\Psi'(w) w]$ for all $w \in \mathcal{N}$.


It remains to prove that:


There exists a Palais–Smale sequence $v_n \in \mathcal{N}$ for $\Phi$ in the level $c = \inf_{\mathcal{N}} \Phi$, that is, $\Phi(v_n) \to c$ and $\Phi'(v_n) \to 0$ in $(H^1_{0}(\Omega))'$.
There exists $u \in \mathcal{N}$ such that $\Phi(u) = \inf_{\mathcal{N}} \Phi$ and $\Phi'(u) = 0$.


Now consider:

Ekeland variational principle: Let $(\mathcal{V},d)$ be a complete metric space and $\Phi : \mathcal{V} \to (-\infty, +\infty]$ a lower semicontinuous functional For every point $u \in \mathcal{V}$ satisfying
$$
 \Phi(u) \leq \inf_{\mathcal{V}} \Phi + \epsilon,
 $$
and for every $\lambda > 0$, there exists some point $v \in \mathcal{V}$ such that
$$
 \Phi(v) \leq \Phi(u), d(u,v) \leq \lambda \text{ and }\Phi(w) + \frac{\epsilon}{\lambda} d(v,w) > \Phi(v)
 $$
for all $w \neq v$.

How to use Ekeland variational principle to prove 7) and 8) ? Is there a good book that do this?

Lets answer first 7). We will use:

Lemma 1 Let $X$ a Banach space, $f,g \in X'$.
Then
$$
 \sup_{g(y) = 0, \|y\| = 1} f(y) = \min_{\lambda \in \mathbb{R}} \|f - \lambda g\|_{X'}
 $$

An an immediate consequence

Lemma 2:
Let $X$ be a Banach space. For $\Phi \in C^1(X, \mathbb{R})$, define $\Psi(u) := \Phi(u) u$ and
the Nehari manifold,
$$
\mathcal{N} = \{ u \in X\backslash \{0\} : \Psi(u) = 0\}.
$$
Also, for $u \in \mathcal{N}$ we define
$$
T_{u} \mathcal{N} := \{ w \in X : \Psi'(u) w = 0\}
$$
and
$$
\|\Phi'(u)\|_{\mathcal{N}} := \sup_{w \in T_u \mathcal{N}, \|w\| = 1} |\Phi'(u) w| = \sup_{\Psi'(u) w = 0, \|w\| = 1} |\Phi'(u) w|,
$$
Then
$$
\|\Phi'(u)\|_{\mathcal{N}} = \min_{\lambda \in \mathbb{R}} \|\Phi'(u) - \lambda \Psi'(u)\|_{X'}.
$$

First we show $\mathcal{N}$ is a closed set. Let $u \in H^1_{0}(\Omega)$ and $u_n \in \mathcal{N}$ such that $u_n \to u$ in $H^1_{0}(\Omega)$. As $\Psi(u_n) \to \Psi(u)$, then $\Psi(u) = 0$. Also by 4), $0 < C \leq \|u_n\|$ and so taking the limit as $n \to \infty$ we obtain $C \leq \|u\|$ which implies $u \neq 0$. Thus $u \in \mathcal{N}$ and so $\mathcal{N}$ is a complete metric space with the metric induced by $\|\cdot\|$. Also notice $\Phi$ is a lower semicontinuous functional, because it is a $C^2$ functinal. Also, by 2), $\Phi$ is bounded from below in $\mathcal{N}$. For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, take $u_n \in \mathcal{N}$ such that
$$
\Phi(u_n) < \inf_{\mathcal{N}} \Phi + \frac{1}{n^2}.
$$
Applying Ekeland variational principle with $\mathcal{V} = \mathcal{N}$, $\lambda = 1/n$ and $\epsilon = 1/n^2$, there exists $v_n \in \mathcal{N}$ such that
$$
(I) \quad \quad  \Phi(v_n) \leq \Phi(u_n), ||u_n - v_n|| \leq \frac{1}{n} \text{ and }\Phi(w) + \frac{1}{n} ||v_n - w|| > \Phi(v_n)
$$
for all $w \neq v_n$. Thus
$$
\inf_{\mathcal{N}} \Phi \leq \Phi(v_n) \leq \Phi(u_n) < \inf_{\mathcal{N}} \Phi(u) + \frac{1}{n^2}
$$
and so
$$
\Phi(v_n) \to c := \inf_{\mathcal{N}} \Phi(u).
$$
By 3) the sequence $v_n$ is bounded. For a fixed $n \in \mathbb{N}$, take $w \in T_{v_n} \mathcal{N}$ with $\|w\| = 1$ and define $h_n : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ by
$$
h_n(s,t) = (\Psi \circ g_n)(t,s), \quad g_n(s,t) = v_n + sw + tv_n.
$$
Notice $h_n \in C^2(\mathbb{R}^2, \mathbb{R})$. Also $h_n(0,0) = \Psi(v_n) = 0$, because $v_n \in \mathcal{N}$. Also by 5),
$$
\frac{\partial h_n}{\partial t} (0,0) = \Psi'(v_n) v_n \neq 0.
$$
By usual Implicit Function Theorem, there exists $\delta_n > 0$ and a a unique map $T_n : (-\delta_n, \delta_n) \to \mathbb{R}$
such that $T_n \in C^1$, $h_n(s, T_n(s)) = 0$ for any $s \in (-\delta_n,\delta_n)$, $T_n(0) = 0$ and
$$
 T_n'(s) = -\frac{\frac{\partial h_n}{\partial s}(s, T_n(s))}{\frac{\partial h_n}{\partial t}(s, T_n(s))}, s \in (-\delta_n, \delta_n).
 $$
Thus $T'_n(0) = 0$, because, by definition, $w \in T_{v_n} \mathcal{N}$ means $\Psi'(v_n) w = 0$ from which we deduce
$$
 T_n'(0) = -\frac{\frac{\partial h_n}{\partial s}(0, 0)}{\frac{\partial h_n}{\partial t}(0, 0)} = - \frac{\Psi'(v_n) w}{ \Psi'(v_n) v_n} = -\frac{0}{\Psi'(v_n) v_n} = 0.
 $$
So
$$
h_n(s, T_n(s)) = 0, s \in (-\delta_n, \delta_n) \implies  \Psi(v_n + sw + T_n(s)v_n) = 0, s \in (-\delta_n, \delta_n)
 $$
that is, $v_n + sw + T_n(s)v_n \in \mathcal{N}$ for all $s \in (-\delta_n, \delta_n)$. Define $\alpha_n : (-\delta_n, \delta_n) \to \mathbb{R}$ by $\alpha_n(s) = v_n + sw + T_n(s)v_n$. Thus, $\alpha_n(0) = v_n $ and $\alpha_n'(0) = w$.  Notice that $\alpha_n(s) \neq v_n$ for small $s$, because, if $\alpha_n(s) = v_n$ for small $s$, then we would get
$$
 w = -\frac{T_n(s)}{s} v_n
 $$
that is
$$
 w = -\frac{T_n(0 + s) - T_n(0)}{s} v_n
 $$
and so, taking the limit as $s \to 0$ it would follows that
$$
 w = -T_n'(0) = 0,
 $$
which is not the case because $\|w\| = 1$ and in particular $w \neq 0$. Thus as $\alpha_n(s) \neq v_n$, by (I)
$$
 \Phi(v_n) < \Phi(\alpha_n(s)) + \frac{1}{n} ||v_n - \alpha_n(s)||.
 $$
Then for $s \in (-\delta_n, \delta_n)$
$$ 
-\frac{1}{n} \left| \left| w + \frac{T_n(0 + s) - T_n(0)}{s} v_n\right|\right| < \frac{(\Phi \circ \alpha_n)(0 + s) - (\Phi \circ \alpha_n)(0)}{s}.
$$
For each $n$ fixed we can take $s \to 0$ in order to obtain
$$ 
-\frac{1}{n} \left| \left| w + T_n'(0) v_n\right|\right| < (\Phi\circ \alpha_n)'(0) = \Phi'(v_n) w,
$$
that is
$$ 
-\frac{1}{n}  \leq  \Phi'(v_n) w, 
$$
for all $w \in \mathcal{N}$. In particular, for $-w$, com $w \in H^1_{0}(\Omega)$,
$$ 
-\frac{1}{n}  \leq  \Phi'(v_n) (-w), 
$$
that is
$$ 
\Phi'(v_n)w\leq \frac{1}{n}.
$$
As consequence
$$
\left|\Phi'(v_n) w\right| \leq \frac{1}{n}, \quad \forall w \in T_{v_n} \mathcal{N}, \|w\| = 1.
$$
Thus
$$
\|\Phi'(v_n)\|_{\ast} := \sup_{w \in T_{v_n} \mathcal{N}, \|w\|=1} |\Phi'(v_n) w| \leq \frac{1}{n},
$$
and so $\|\Phi'(v_n)\|_{\ast} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.  By Lemma 2,
$$
(II) \quad \quad 
 \|\Phi'(v_n)\|_{\ast} = \min_{\lambda \in \mathbb{R}}\|\Phi'(v_n) - \lambda \Psi'(v_n)\|_{(H^1_{0}(\Omega))'} = \|\Phi'(v_n) - \lambda_n \Psi'(v_n)\|_{(H^1_{0}(\Omega))'} \to 0.
$$
Thus by 3)
$$
 |(\Phi'(v_n) - \lambda_n \Psi'(v_n))(v_n)| \leq \|\Phi'(v_n) - \lambda_n \Psi'(v_n)\|_{(H^1_{0}(\Omega))'} \|v_n\| \leq C  \|\Phi'(v_n) - \lambda_n \Psi'(v_n)\|_{(H^1_{0}(\Omega))'}
 $$
and so
$$
(III) \quad \quad - \lambda_n \Psi'(v_n)(v_n) =  \Phi'(v_n)(v_n) - \lambda_n \Psi'(v_n)(v_n) \to 0.
$$
Now we show $1/[\Psi'(v_n)(v_n)]$ is bounded.  First, 6) there exists $C_1 > 0$ such that
\begin{equation}\label{Sergipe_1}
 -C_1 < \frac{1}{\Psi'(v_n)(v_n)}.
\end{equation}
Also, by continuous immersion of $H^1_{0}(\Omega)$ and by 3), there exists $C_2 > 0$ such that
$$
|\Psi'(v_n) v_n| \leq  C_2
$$
and so $-C_2 \leq \Psi'(v_n) v_n \leq C_2$. But as $\Phi'(v_n) v_n < 0$ (see 6)) we obtain
\begin{equation}\label{Sergipe_2}
 \frac{1}{\Psi'(v_n) v_n} \leq -C_3.
\end{equation}
Therefore by the sequence $1/[\Psi'(v_n)(v_n)]$ is bounded. Thus by (III)
$$
\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \lambda_n = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} [\lambda_n \Psi'(v_n) v_n] \frac{1}{\Psi'(v_n) v_n} = 0.
$$
Finally,
\begin{align*}
 \|\Phi'(v_n)\|_{(H^1_{0,r}(B))'} & \leq \|\Phi'(v_n) - \lambda_n \Psi'(v_n)\|_{(H^1_{0,r}(B))'} + \|\lambda_n \Psi'(v_n)\|_{(H^1_{0,r}(B))'} \\
 & =  \|\Phi'(v_n) - \lambda_n \Psi'(v_n)\|_{(H^1_{0,r}(B))'} + |\lambda_n|\| \Psi'(v_n)\|_{(H^1_{0,r}(B))'}.
\end{align*}
Again, by continous immersion of $H^1_{0}(\Omega)$ and by 3), there exists $C_4 > 0$ such that
$$
\| \Psi'(v_n)\|_{(H^1_{0,r}(B))'} \leq C_4
$$
and so by (II) $\Phi'(v_n) \to 0$.
To prove 8), we will use that the functional satisfies $(PS)_c$ condition (which is  easy to check). If we take the sequence of 7), then there exists $u \in H^1_{0}(\Omega)$ such that $v_n \to u$ in $H^1_{0}(\Omega)$. Thus, $\Phi(u_n) \to \Phi(u)$ implies $\Phi(u) = c$. Also $\Phi'(u_n) \to \Phi'(u)$ implies $\Phi'(u) = 0$.
